# What kind of push-on connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

I have a push-on connector, that looks to be male, but searching for "male push-on connector" doesn't yield any useful results. I have found tons of female push-on connectors, though.

What type of connector is this?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for 'male spade connector" or 'male Faston' (a trade name).  You'll have to confirm the dimensions to determine compatibility.

I don't see a feature on that part to retain the connector in an insulator or housing, so it may be intended to have a plastic insulator shrunk around it.

Comment: Yeah looks like it's the "2.8 type" listed here: https://www.amazon.ca/Glarks-Connector-Terminal-Insulating-Assortment/dp/B07FCFH84Q

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got the connectors but don’t know what kind of crimpers will crimp correctly by curling the metal over the metal stick of the thermal fuse. Do you know the exact name of the type of crimpers or some other info so I could find them online? I have no vocabulary so it’s so hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

Look up 'spade/lucar/faston male/female terminals/connectors'.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what kind of crimpers can crimp the connectors? I have the connectors but the crimpers I have don’t work.

Comment: Hi Neil, Please search for 'spade terminal crimping tool'.